# Can't mass-assign protected attributes: user, course

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, relationship

I want to use Rails to do a project about school students and courses relationship. A students can have many courses, and a course can have many students. Therefore, I think the relationship between students and courses is "many-to-many"

I went to the console :

```
u = User.first
User Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" LIMIT 1
...
c = Course.first
Course Load (0.8ms)  SELECT "courses".* FROM "courses" LIMIT 1
...
UserCourseship.create( :user => u, :course => c )
```

Then the error I got is:

```
ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error: Can't mass-assign protected attributes:user, course
```

Here is my `user.rb`

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_courseships
  has_many :courses, :through => :user_courseships

    def self.from_omniauth(auth)
        where(auth.slice(:provider, :uid)).first_or_initialize.tap do |user|
            user.provider = auth.provider
            user.uid = auth.uid
            user.name = auth.info.name
            user.oauth_token = auth.credentials.token
            user.oauth_expires_at = Time.at(auth.credentials.expires_at)
            user.save!
        end
    end

    def facebook
      @facebook ||= Koala::Facebook::API.new(oauth_token)
    end
end
```

My `course.rb`

```
class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_courseships
  has_many :users, :through => :user_courseships
  attr_accessible :name, :sn, :time
end
```

And the relationship `user_courseship.rb`

```
class UserCourseship < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :course
  attr_accessible :course_id, :user_id
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
UserCourseship.create( :user => u, :course => c )
```

To this:

```
UserCourseship.create( :user_id => u.id, :course_id => c.id )
```

And then it should work.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a courses to a student (or vice versa) like this:

```
c = Course.first
s = Student.first
s.save

s.courses << c

#Other way around

c.students << s
c.save
```

and have a look at: accepts_nested_attributes_for

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#mass-assignment

Comment: Thanks for answering. But I think user is the student. So the user(student) can choose the course.

Comment: Yes. In your example. Whats the problem then? Then you add the student (s) to the Course (c) (i.e. c.students << s)

Comment: I don't know why I got this error message: `ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error: Can't mass-assign protected attributes:user, course`

Answer (score 1):

Mass assignment on by default is implemented since rails 3.2.3 after github fell victim to an attack .

Therefor you are now required to either turn of the mass assignment warning (not such a good idea)

or set the protect level of attributes either by black or whitelist in the models.

whitelist can be done by:(I highly suggest this method)

```
attr_accessible :user_id, :course
```

or set it by black list:

```
attr_protected :is_admin, :pasword_salt
```

check this out for more info 
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/MassAssignmentSecurity/ClassMethods.html